# wordpress count number of images in a particular post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a wordpress loop that shows all the posts. I need to have a count of all the images for a particular post.

```
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ) );

    $count = count( $attachments );
    $specific = array();
    $i = 1;
          foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
         $specific[$attachment->ID] = $i;
    ++$i;
    }  ?> <a href="#"><?php echo $count; ?></a>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

the problem is that, it doesn't works and it does not display images count.

Comment: what do you get if you do a var_dump($attachments) ?

Comment: the field `post_parent` within the attachment is set to a post ID, in which it was uploaded when creating a particular post. It does not mean, that the image is used in the post. You would be better off counting `<img` tags inside `$post->post_content`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Function Reference/get attached media like this:

with the_post();

```
$count = count( get_attached_media( 'image' ) );
```

or with post id

```
$count = count( get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID ) );
```

Doc: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution and for more information   visit https://blog.josemcastaneda.com/2014/03/18/get-image-count-in-wordpress-post/

```
// Get all the galleries in the current post
    $galleries = get_post_galleries( get_the_ID(), false );
    // Count all the galleries
    $total_gal = count( $galleries );
    /**
     * count all the images
     * @param array $array The array needed
     * @return int returns the number of images in the post
     */
    function _get_total_images( $array ){
        $key = 0;
        $src = 0;
        while ( $key < count( $array ) ){
            $src += count( $array[$key]['src'] );
            $key++;
        }
        return intval( $src );
    }

    echo _get_total_images( $galleries );
```

Comment: This only finds media in Galleries. There may be media directly referenced in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic PHP to do this. Each image begins with a repeatable HTML pattern, so just count the occurrences with `substr_count()`:

```
$image_count = substr_count( get_the_content(), '<img' );
```

That will give you the number of `<img>`'s in the post.